# Meteor Integration Testing Examples

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am searching for meteor Client/server Testing Examples, but I have not found much more on this, I have read velocity for this, but not got much examples to create testcases, Can anyone help me to provide some links, so that I can learn more on this, Specially I am looking for client side testing first.

where i am looking for this

I have required to login, logout, expect data in collections, insert data, remove data from client side,

Any Help is really appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha seems to be very popular for testing in meteor https://atmospherejs.com/mike/mocha. This will install velocity and mocha.

Here are some examples for both client and server side tests using mocha.  https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-examples/tree/master/leaderboard-mocha

Here is a cool book abut meteor testing. I have yet to read it but it seems really cool other than the fact that its 30 bucks. http://www.meteortesting.com/

Comment: Hi, Can I get some more links, The link http://www.meteortesting.com/chapter/velocity is paid book

Comment: Hi,I have created a simple web app using https://www.meteor.com/try, which displaying some data of collection tasks, can someone inform me how can I write its testcase to expect tasks collection length, its data values etc,